# Lost timezone value in Redshift with PostgreSQL external table

Tags: postgresql, timezone, amazon-redshift

1. PostgreSQL client timezone is KST. An example query result:

   ```
   2024-01-25 23:59:59.000000 +09:00
   ```
2. In AWS Redshift, querying by external table returns this:

   ```
   2024-01-25 23:59:59+00
   ```

I've lost the timezone value: `+09:00` → `+00`.

If Redshift is set to timezone `'Asia/Seoul'` then I get:

```
2024-01-26 08:59:59+09
```

Timezone is not lost but it is also not the same.

How do I pass the timestamp along with the timezone information from an external table in Redshift?

Comment: Please [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77898669/2) paste code as pictures: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Redshift [external tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html) only support plain `timestamp` (without time zone).

What's probably happening is you're trying to feed your `timestamptz` from somewhere to this plain `timestamp` field of an external table, which truncates the offset. If you then try to feed that into a `timestamptz` column, it'll assume `+00`.
That's effectively a completely different point in time, shifted away from the original by the TZ offset.

To fix this, link the external source as a regular `timestamp` and restore the shift using [`at time zone`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_AT_TIME_ZONE.html) before feeding it into the destination `timestamptz` field: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Msi6CO92)

```
set timezone='Asia/Seoul';
create table external_table(external_timestamp_field timestamp);
insert into external_table values('2024-01-25 23:59:59.000000 +09:00') returning *;
```

| external_timestamp_field |
| --- |
| 2024-01-25 23:59:59 |

```sql
set timezone='Asia/Seoul';
create table destination_table as 
  select external_timestamp_field at time zone 'Asia/Seoul' as imported_timestamptz
  from external_table;
select * from destination_table;
```

| imported_timestamptz |
| --- |
| 2024-01-25 23:59:59+09 |

You might want to keep the information about the origin time zone in a separate field, especially if you're dealing with a source that uses multiple. Remember that the time zone information or the offset is not an integral part of the `timestamptz`: it's only used to align it internally, then discarded. All timestamps store a *when*, not a *where*. If the latter is also important to you, you need to save it separately.

Comment: sorry not external table , it is external schema for postgresql, i saw date type is timestamp with time zone in redshift console v2

Comment: when i directly connect postgresql in query result -> 2024-01-25 23:59:59.000000 +09:00, but in redshift, external schema postgresql querying -> 2024-01-25 23:59:59+00

Comment: @user23314066 My point stands: however you've set things up, the problem you're experiencing seems to be the effect of time zone getting truncated, and the workaround I suggested should work as demonstrated.